# How to display images in recycler view with different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

i want to display images in Recycler View

[image: like this]

You can see images have no fixed height and width. just randomly shown in different sizes.
i have considered `StaggeredLayoutManager` for `recyclerview` but the problem with that we have to show vertically or horizontally with fixed height in that. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Using StaggeredGridLayoutManager : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html and CardView.

Comment: staggeredGridLayoutManager is not displaying like this. please see image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make different kind of viewholders in your recyclerview adapter and inflate views according to image types

Answer (score 0):

You can cerate different view holder for different position or item of different sizes. Please take a reference from here :
 [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)